# MySQL get row before and after of current row within query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have five tables in MySQL which I am generating some reports from. I will abstract the table names slightly for display purposes. Let's assume the tables I am working with are as described below:

```
History  (id, serial, date, time) : Stores historic data, this is the main
                                    column we query.
Serial   (id, serial)             : Stores serial numbers used in the next
                                    3 tables.
Employee (id, serial_id, name)
Event    (id, serial_id, name)
Location (id, serial_id, name)
```

**EDIT:** Rewrote the whole question in hopes that it is clearer and easier to understand...

I need to query for events, also if an employee serial is found in history directly **PRIOR** to a row with a serial matching an event, that employee will be associated with that event, likewise, if a location is found in the history directly **AFTER** the row with a serial matching an event, that location will be associated with that event.

Sample data:

```
History:
+------+------------+------------+----------+
| id   | serial     | date       | time     |
+------+------------+------------+----------+
| 1    | 00001234   | 2012-09-25 | 09:00:00 |
+------+------------+------------+----------+
| 2    | 00001235   | 2012-09-25 | 09:01:00 |
+------+------------+------------+----------+
| 3    | 00001236   | 2012-09-25 | 09:02:00 |
+------+------------+------------+----------+
| 4    | 00001235   | 2012-09-25 | 09:05:00 |
+------+------------+------------+----------+
| 5    | 00001236   | 2012-09-25 | 09:07:00 |
+------+------------+------------+----------+
| 6    | 00001235   | 2012-09-25 | 09:10:00 |
+------+------------+------------+----------+
| 7    | 00001235   | 2012-09-25 | 09:11:00 |
+------+------------+------------+----------+
| 8    | 00001235   | 2012-09-25 | 09:12:00 |
+------+------------+------------+----------+
| 9    | 00001236   | 2012-09-25 | 09:15:00 |
+------+------------+------------+----------+
| 10   | 00001234   | 2012-09-25 | 09:20:00 |
+------+------------+------------+----------+
| 11   | 00001236   | 2012-09-25 | 09:25:00 |
+------+------------+------------+----------+

Serial:
+----------+------------+
| id       | serial     |
+----------+------------+
| 1        | 00001234   |
+----------+------------+
| 2        | 00001235   |
+----------+------------+
| 3        | 00001236   |
+----------+------------+

Employee:
+----------+------------+-------------+
| id       | serial_id  | name        |
+----------+------------+-------------+
| 1        | 1          | John Smith  |
+----------+------------+-------------+

Event:
+----------+------------+-------------+
| id       | serial_id  | name        |
+----------+------------+-------------+
| 1        | 2          | Event 1     |
+----------+------------+-------------+

Location:
+----------+------------+-------------+
| id       | serial_id  | name        |
+----------+------------+-------------+
| 1        | 3          | Location 1  |
+----------+------------+-------------+
```

If I were to do a normal LEFT JOIN query (just for clarity as the difference in results), with the following query, results would be:

```
SELECT
    history.id,
    history.serial,
    history.date,
    history.time,
    employee.name as 'employee',
    event.name as 'event',
    location.name as 'location'
FROM history
LEFT JOIN serial ON history.serial = serial.serial
LEFT JOIN employee ON serial.id = employee.serial_id
LEFT JOIN event ON serial.id = event.serial_id
LEFT JOIN location ON location.id = location.serial_id
ORDER BY date, time
```

Results on normal LEFT JOIN are (for clarity only, I don't need this result set):

```
+----+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+
| id | serial   | date       | time     | employee   | event    | location   |
+----+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+
| 1  | 00001234 | 2012-09-25 | 09:00:00 | John Smith | NULL     | NULL       |
+----+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+
| 2  | 00001235 | 2012-09-25 | 09:01:00 | NULL       | Event 1  | NULL       |
+----+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+
| 3  | 00001236 | 2012-09-25 | 09:02:00 | NULL       | NULL     | Location 1 |
+----+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+
| 4  | 00001235 | 2012-09-25 | 09:05:00 | NULL       | Event 1  | NULL       |
+----+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+
| 5  | 00001236 | 2012-09-25 | 09:07:00 | NULL       | NULL     | Location 1 |
+----+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+
| 6  | 00001235 | 2012-09-25 | 09:10:00 | NULL       | Event 1  | NULL       |
+----+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+
| 7  | 00001235 | 2012-09-25 | 09:11:00 | NULL       | Event 1  | NULL       |
+----+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+
| 8  | 00001235 | 2012-09-25 | 09:12:00 | NULL       | Event 1  | NULL       |
+----+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+
| 9  | 00001236 | 2012-09-25 | 09:15:00 | NULL       | NULL     | Location 1 |
+-----+---------+------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+
| 10 | 00001234 | 2012-09-25 | 09:20:00 | John Smith | NULL     | NULL       |
+----+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+
| 11 | 00001236 | 2012-09-25 | 09:25:00 | NULL       | NULL     | Location 1 |
+----+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+------------+
```

The query should be based off the event, event should never be NULL. It should look at the row **PRIOR** and label it as employee (or null if no match), it should look at the row **AFTER** and label it as location (or null if no match). Example of what the result should be, using the above data:

```
Result should be:
+----------+------------+------------+------------+----------+------------+
| e_serial | date       | time       | employee   | event    | location   |
+----------+------------+------------+------------+----------+------------+
| 00001235 | 2012-09-25 | 09:01:00   | John Smith | Event 1  | Location 1 |
+----------+------------+------------+------------+----------+------------+
| 00001235 | 2012-09-25 | 09:05:00   | NULL       | Event 1  | Location 1 |
+----------+------------+------------+------------+----------+------------+
| 00001235 | 2012-09-25 | 09:10:00   | NULL       | Event 1  | NULL       |
+----------+------------+------------+------------+----------+------------+
| 00001235 | 2012-09-25 | 09:11:00   | NULL       | Event 1  | NULL       |
+----------+------------+------------+------------+----------+------------+
| 00001235 | 2012-09-25 | 09:12:00   | NULL       | Event 1  | Location 1 |
+----------+------------+------------+------------+----------+------------+
```

I am not sure if this is possible with some set of sub selects or something, I think this is way over my league with SQL. Currently I have this working with application logic, but thought it might be cleaner and faster to handle it with SQL only.

Any help would be fantastic.

Comment: much better if you post the record of each table not the result of the joined queries :D

Comment: rewrote the question is hopes that it should be much clearer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone else ever runs into the issue, posting the solution here. Thanks to dianuj for steering me in the right direction for it.

```
SELECT
    serial.serial as 'e_serial',
    @dt:=TIMESTAMP(history.date, history.time) as 'date_time',
    history.date,
    history.time,
    (SELECT
        employee.name
    FROM
        history
        LEFT JOIN serial ON history.serial = serial.serial
        LEFT JOIN employee ON employee.serial_id = serial.id
    WHERE
        TIMESTAMP(history.date, history.time) = (
            SELECT
                max(TIMESTAMP(history.date, history.time))
            FROM
                history
            WHERE TIMESTAMP(history.date, history.time) < @dt
        )
    ) as 'employee',
    event.name as 'event',
    (SELECT
        location.name
    FROM
        history
        LEFT JOIN serial ON history.serial = serial.serial
        LEFT JOIN location ON location.serial_id = serial.id
    WHERE
        TIMESTAMP(history.date, history.time) > @dt
    LIMIT 1
    ) as 'location'
FROM history
LEFT JOIN serial ON history.serial = serial.serial
LEFT JOIN event ON serial.id = event.serial_id
WHERE event.name IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY history.date, history.time
```

And the results

```
+----------+---------------------+------------+----------+------------+---------+------------+
| e_serial | date_time           | date       | time     | employee   | event   | location   |
+----------+---------------------+------------+----------+------------+---------+------------+
| 00001235 | 2012-09-25 09:01:00 | 2012-09-25 | 09:01:00 | John Smith | Event 1 | Location 1 |
| 00001235 | 2012-09-25 09:05:00 | 2012-09-25 | 09:05:00 | NULL       | Event 1 | Location 1 |
| 00001235 | 2012-09-25 09:10:00 | 2012-09-25 | 09:10:00 | NULL       | Event 1 | NULL       |
| 00001235 | 2012-09-25 09:11:00 | 2012-09-25 | 09:11:00 | NULL       | Event 1 | NULL       |
| 00001235 | 2012-09-25 09:12:00 | 2012-09-25 | 09:12:00 | NULL       | Event 1 | Location 1 |
+----------+---------------------+------------+----------+------------+---------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT serial_id AS `serial`,
(SELECT `date` FROM History WHERE serial_id= event2.serial_id ) AS `date`,
(SELECT `time` FROM History WHERE serial_id= event2.serial_id ) AS `time`,
(SELECT `name` FROM event1 WHERE serial_id= event2.serial_id ) AS `event1`,`name` AS event2,
(SELECT `name` FROM event3 WHERE serial_id= event2.serial_id ) AS `event1`
FROM event2
```

your histroy table should be `History (id, serial_id, date, time)` , must contain `serial_id` instead of `serial name`

for your scenario hope so  it works fine

```
SELECT serial_id AS `serial`,
(SELECT `date` FROM History WHERE `serial` = (SELECT `serial` FROM `serial` WHERE id = event2.serial_id LIMIT 0,1)) AS `date`,
(SELECT `time` FROM History WHERE `serial`= (SELECT `serial` FROM `serial` WHERE id = event2.serial_id LIMIT 0,1)) AS `time`,
(SELECT `name` FROM event1 WHERE serial_id= event2.serial_id ) AS `event1`,
`name` AS event2,
(SELECT `name` FROM event3 WHERE serial_id= event2.serial_id ) AS `event1`
FROM event2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately it is not possible to attach the serial_id column to the History table. The data in history is fed straight from hardware, and all the hardware provides is the serial number.

Comment: you can check the second query

Comment: Thanks for that, It gives me something to work towards, however the from your example, event1.serial_id is not the same as event2.serial_id, so I cannot use them to join. What I need is to check the row BEFORE event 2 and AFTER row 2 and check for matches. I think I might rewrite the question to clarify, maybe it's too confusing.

Comment: if you understand mu above query it simply fetches record of that `serial_id` which is in event2 table not feteching all the records only fetching those records which exists in event2 as your question describes

Comment: hope the new question makes more sense